# generalised eigenvalue problem with matrices with positive real parts

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it possible to demonstrate that the complex eigenvalues of the generalised eigenvalue problem $Ax=\lambda B x$ have positive real parts if we know that both $A$ and $B$ have complex eigenvalues with positive real parts?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.  As a counterexample, take
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&10\\0&1}, B = \pmatrix{1&0\\10&1}
$$
note that $A^{-1}B$ has eigenvalues with negative real part.